# SwiftUI - Need help troubleshooting trailing closure that does not accept a closure

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

`I am learning swiftui and have run into a problem with trailing closures. I have tried to create a very simple app to practice some basic principles of passing data between views.

I have a client model, enclosure model and then views for adding and displaying the clients into a project list. The apps content view displays a list of all clients added. Within each client, the idea would be that you could then add enclosures etc to the project.

Here is the model I've set up.

```
import SwiftData
import Observation
import SwiftUI

@Model
final class Client {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var location: String
    var selectedJob: Person.RawValue
    

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, location: String, selectedJob: Person.RawValue) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.selectedJob = selectedJob
    }
    
}
extension Client {
    enum Person: String, CaseIterable {
        case homeOwner = "Home Owner"
        case contractor = "Contractor"
        case designer = "Designer"
    }
}

@Model
class Enclosure: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var room: String
    var unitType: String
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), room: String, unitType: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.room = room
        self.unitType = unitType
    }
}
```

This is the detail view where I am getting the error "Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure"

```
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Query(sort: \Enclosure.room, order: .forward, animation: .default) private var enclosures: [Enclosure]
    
    @State private var showingAddEnclosure = false
    @State private var showingAddMirror = false
    
    
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var location: String = ""
    
    
    @State private var selectedJob = Client.Person.homeOwner
    
    @State var client: Client
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section("Details") {
                    TextField("Full Name", text: $client.name)
                    TextField("Location", text: $client.location)
                    
                    Picker("Job Type", selection: $selectedJob) {
                        ForEach(Client.Person.allCases, id: \.self) { selected in
                            Text(selected.rawValue).tag(selected)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section("Enclosures") {
                    List {
                        ForEach(client.enclosures) { enclosure in
                            NavigationLink(destination: EnclosureDetailView()) {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text(enclosure.room)
                                        Text(enclosure.unitType)
                                    }
                            }
                            .swipeActions {
                                Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
                                    modelContext.delete(enclosure)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Project Details")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Menu {
                        Button {
                            showingAddEnclosure.toggle()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Add Enclosure")
                        }
                        Button {
                            showingAddMirror.toggle()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Add Mirror")
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add", systemImage: "ellipsis.circle")
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddEnclosure) {
                EnclosureView()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddMirror) {
                EnclosureView()
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I have tried commenting out different parts of the code and when I remove the ForEach in the enclosure section the error resolves. I don't understand what syntax is incorrect so any help is appreciated.

I also tried taking the code out of the form and creating a function with a viewbuilder but my limited knowledge didn't get far with that method.

Any help is appreciated and more importantly than a solution I am hoping someone can help me better understand how to problem solve an issue like this so I can do it myself.`

Comment: Weird error message. May be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77246761/swiftui-form-error-trailing-closure-passed-to-parameter-of-type-formstylec

Comment: The error message is different (and perhaps more helpful) when you comment out the first section inside the ```Form```. In particular, it shows this: Value of type 'Client' has no dynamic member 'enclosures' using key path from root type 'Client'

Comment: @BenzyNeez when i commented out the first section I get three errors. the first is on the foreach "Referencing subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires wrapper 'Binding<Client>'", then the first text in the vstack "Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<Subject>' conform to 'StringProtocol'", and finally on the modelcontext delete "Instance method 'delete' requires that 'Binding<_>' conform to 'PersistentModel'...I don't know what those mean or what steps I should try to resolve them. My guess is something in the models.

Comment: @rhythmsticks Swift compiler errors are notoriously unhelpful and misleading, especially when something simple like a closing bracket is missing. In this case, the error that makes the most sense is that your class ```Client``` has no member property ```enclosures```. In other words, ```ForEach(client.enclosures)``` is invalid. So I would start by fixing that, then the other error messages might turn more meaningful.

Comment: @BenzyNeez thanks for your help. So I think it's clear I don't know what I'm doing. I tried changing my model to include the enclosure in the extension on Client. That removes the trailing closure error and then puts it on the foreach, Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Client.Enclosure' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection' and also throws an error on the query for enclosures Cannot find 'Enclosure' in scope. So I sort of get that a foreach needs more than one item to loop over and I thought that's what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on the comments, this case is an example of a particularly unhelpful and misleading error from Xcode. I found that by commenting out different parts of the code I would get different error messages and at one point it at last reported something useful:

> Value of type 'Client' has no dynamic member 'enclosures' using key path from root type 'Client'

So I think your main issue is that your class `Client` does not have a member property `enclosures`, which means the statement `ForEach(client.enclosures)` is invalid.

When I changed it to the following, all errors disappear and it compiles (at least):

```swift
ForEach(enclosures) { enclosure in // not client.enclosures
```

All other code is the same as what you posted, except that I had to improvise the two missing views:

```swift
struct EnclosureDetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("EnclosureDetailView")
    }
}

struct EnclosureView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("EnclosureDetailView")
    }
}
```

If this leads you to new errors and you need more help then I would suggest you create a new post. You will probably get a better response another time if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with emphasis on *minimal*. I suspect that the reason you didn't get much help on this occasion (and the question was downvoted) was because the code you provided was not complete (the views above were missing) and it wasn't minimal. Reducing the code to a minimum is actually a good way of isolating the problem - you may find that the errors turn more meaningful and you will be able to resolve the problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks. This did resolve the trailing closure error and code compiles. Appreciate your help and further explanation.